# Creating a context-menu with OSMbonuspack_v5.1

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am using osmbonuspack_v5.1 to handle my OpenStreet mapview and the long-press events on the map. Now I need to bring a context menu up when there is a long press event. `registerForContextMenu (View view)` does not work as the map view is not getting the events due to added `overlays`. I was wondering if there is already some implementation in osmbonuspack to bring up a context menu.

My code so far.

```
@Override
public boolean longPressHelper(GeoPoint geoPoint) {
    // show the menu here to send event
    latitude = Double.toString(geoPoint.getLatitude());
    longitude = Double.toString(geoPoint.getLongitude());

//        ServiceAdapter.publishGlobal(TOPIC_NAME, EVENT_NAME, latitude + longitude);
    Intent listViewIntent = new Intent(this, ListViewActivity.class);
    startActivity(listViewIntent);
    mapView.invalidate();
//        Toast.makeText(this, "Event at (" + latitude + " , " + longitude + ")", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
}
```

As you can see I am manually trying to bring up a List view activity on long press. if there is no default implementation probably that's what  I will have to do.

Comment: Trying putting a transparent view over `mapview` and register context menu with that!

Comment: @MuhammadBabar the problem is there is already an overlay added on top of mapview. This overlay is responsible for giving a callback when there is a long press event on the map with the location object of that point. I can not remove it. Nor can I register this for registerForContextMenu as its not a view object

Comment: Please read my suggestion carefully you can for instance put a FrameLayout on top of your MapView in the hierarchy and try to register the context menu with framelayout. FrameLayout (transparent) will appear on top your map and overlays!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But If I put a FrameLayout on top of the overlay then the overlay will stop receiving the long press events which I need. Won't that happen?

Comment: I would suggest you to give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

"I was wondering if there is already some implementation in osmbonuspack to bring up a context menu."

=> Yes, in [OSMNavigator MapActivity](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/blob/master/OSMNavigator/src/main/java/com/osmnavigator/MapActivity.java).

There are 2 tricks to skirt (hooking the menu, passing the geoPoint pressed), look at the comments in the source code.